# How to build layout as shown in image

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

i am using linear layout with weight but it is not looking consistent on different screen sizes(only handsets). i need the text should be exactly below the image icon. so is there any way to create this layout in android
**here is my xml code**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/progress_count_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="23.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/one_ic_iv"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step01c_active_incomplete"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9.5"
                    android:background="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/two_ic_iv"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step02a_inactive_incomplete"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="12"
                    android:background="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/three_ic_iv"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step03a_inactive_incomplete"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="12"
                    android:background="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/four_ic_iv"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step04a_inactive_incomplete"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="12"
                    android:background="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/five_ic_iv"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step05a_inactive_incomplete"/>
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/progress_text_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/create_acc_progress_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:text="Create\nAccount"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    fontPath="HVD Fonts - BrandonText-Light.otf"/>
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/accept_terms_progress_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:text="Verify\nPhone"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    fontPath="HVD Fonts - BrandonText-Light.otf"/>
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/verify_phone_progress_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:text="Accept\nTerms"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    fontPath="HVD Fonts - BrandonText-Light.otf"/>
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/link_bank_progress_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:text="Link\nBank"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    fontPath="HVD Fonts - BrandonText-Light.otf"/>
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/get_approved_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:text="Get\nApproved"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    fontPath="HVD Fonts - BrandonText-Light.otf"/>
            </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show us what your layout renders?

Comment: Its a step progress indicator. There is a library for it.

Comment: @Piyush:i found one library but the view of progress indicator from that library is different from mine.

Comment: @sunilkushwah is it solved??

Comment: @Aditya Vyas-Lakhan: not yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution of my question , i used constraint layout for this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin_wizard_bar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_margin_wizard_bar">


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.06" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step01c_active_incomplete"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Create\nAccount"
        android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small_14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1506666" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_wizard_line"
        android:background="@color/CelestialBlue"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2573333" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step02a_inactive_incomplete"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Verify\nMobile"
        android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small_14sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.348" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_wizard_line"
        android:background="@color/CelestialBlue"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4333333" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step03c_active_incomplete"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Accept\nTerms"
        android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small_14sp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5666666" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_wizard_line"
        android:background="@color/CelestialBlue"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.652" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step04a_inactive_incomplete"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Link\nBank"
        android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small_14sp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7426666" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_wizard_line"
        android:background="@color/CelestialBlue"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8493333" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wizard_5step_step05a_inactive_incomplete"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Get\nApproved"
        android:textColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small_14sp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.94" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your text is coming up out of sync with the images, you might try to include a vertical LinearLayout for each component (image and text).

So **use one big horizontal LinearLayout with 5 vertical LinearLayouts inside it**. Rather than two horizontal LinearLayouts like you have now.

As another option, you could try to build this with ConstraintLayout. It will allow you to align things such that they don't get out of sync.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: @Michale Vescovo: what about the line connecting the image icons

Comment: You can put those in between. So there could be 5 vertical LinearLayouts with 4 lines in between them.

Comment: there are two problem in this approach first how we are going to position this line,second line will not be able to touch the image icon because there is a vertical linear layout between image icon and line

Comment: If it's hard to get them to touch because of the text being too wide then you could put the line behind it all and have the images sit in front. So use a FrameLayout, then on top of that put one big long line, then the big horizontal LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
try to do like this : 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    enter code here



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Create Account"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Create Account"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Create Account"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>[layout should look like this ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lim80.png
```

Comment: where is the line connecting the views

Comment: add a view as desired in between inner linearlayouts  or use relative layout as parent for overlapping this layout over a line behind

Answer (score 0):

Try this library it will give you result

https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView

https://github.com/anton46/Android-StepsView

https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar

Java Code

```
HorizontalStepView setpview5 = (HorizontalStepView) mView.findViewById(R.id.step_view5);
        List<StepBean> stepsBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
        StepBean stepBean0 = new StepBean("接单",1);
        StepBean stepBean1 = new StepBean("打包",1);
        StepBean stepBean2 = new StepBean("出发",1);
        StepBean stepBean3 = new StepBean("送单",0);
        StepBean stepBean4 = new StepBean("完成",-1);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean0);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean1);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean2);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean3);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean4);


        setpview5
                .setStepViewTexts(stepsBeanList)//总步骤
                .setTextSize(12)//set textSize
                .setStepsViewIndicatorCompletedLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white))//设置StepsViewIndicator完成线的颜色
                .setStepsViewIndicatorUnCompletedLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.uncompleted_text_color))//设置StepsViewIndicator未完成线的颜色
                .setStepViewComplectedTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white))//设置StepsView text完成线的颜色
                .setStepViewUnComplectedTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.uncompleted_text_color))//设置StepsView text未完成线的颜色
                .setStepsViewIndicatorCompleteIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.complted))//设置StepsViewIndicator CompleteIcon
                .setStepsViewIndicatorDefaultIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.default_icon))//设置StepsViewIndicator DefaultIcon
                .setStepsViewIndicatorAttentionIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.attention));//设置StepsViewIndicator AttentionIcon
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this as per your requirement.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Space
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/one_ic_iv"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_crop" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/create_acc_progress_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/one_ic_iv"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Create\nAccount"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/one_ic_iv1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_crop" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/create_acc_progress_tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/one_ic_iv1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Create\nAccount"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use LinearLayout with `orientation: horizontal` and then put separate RelativeLayouts for each progresses. I am suggesting RelativeLayout because then you can use its positional tags like `android:layout_toLeftOf` to align your textvies or imageviews.